# Href Links not working in Firefox

Tags: firefox, hyperlink, cross-browser, html

Please help!  I have tried using Firebug to see why my href's are not click-able but I can't figure it out.  I don't use tables.  The site is http://spiritfestcorpus.com/

The big circular image is wrapped in a href

I'd really appreciate any suggestions.

Here is the code from line 357 if you VIEW SOURCE in Firefox

```
<div id="slideshow_wrapper" )">
            <div id="frame"></div>
            <div id="slideshow_container">
                <div id="slideshow">

                            <a style="z-index:9999999; position: absolute;" id="cdImage1" href="concertsbuy.aspx?eventId=53"><img id="Repeater1_ctl00_cdImage" src="images/slideshow/home/albums/2012/SPIRIT_Fest_Corpus/LMG_DC12Circle.png" style="border-width:0px;" /></a>
```

Comment: What happens if you remove `position: absolute`?

Comment: Try validating your HTML.  This paren isn't going to help: `<div id="slideshow_wrapper" )">`

Comment: Or that fun little extra quote.

Answer (score 1):

with `position: absolute` you *must* specify width and height. And if you are going to specify width and height on an `a` tag, you need to use `display: block`